# How can I create a secure auto-login system for my client-server program?

Tags: java, python, database, sqlite, network-programming

I want to create a auto login system for my client-server program.
I have an idea but I think it is very insecure. So.. can anyone explain to me how to do this in a secure way so nobody can get into my account with "just copying files".

My idea:
As the Client registered at the server he get an identifier and a securitytoken from the server. The client and server are saving these in a sqlite database. When the client starts the program he checks if he has a database. If he has he sends the data inside the database to the server. In case the server has got the data the client is signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this authentication.
Exchanging a Token is a good idea. The token must be unique for every client in the application, and the server, in a authentication phase (middleware) verifies if the token exist on the database.
If it does, then the request is processed normally. If it fails, then you return a 401 error code.

There are multiple types of tokens. It can be a random token that you might need to check on a DB if that token is valid, or a cryptographically signed token with a private key of the server. This approach adds the advantage that you don't need to check on DB if that token is valid as it can be validated using the server's public key. An example of these are Json Web Tokens https://jwt.io

You must also think on a method to revoke the tokens if you wish that a client no longer connects into your system.

Finally, it's necessary to mention that the security of this system is valid as long as the communication between client and server is encrypted using SSL/TLS or any other method. If you're using plain text communications, anyone in the middle of the network can get your token and send requests on the client's behalf.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. But how can I achieve that the client cannot copy his file where the token is saved to another pc and log in from there without any problems. Because that would be very problematic

Comment: If that's the case, you might want to use something physical on the client to generate part of the token such as the MAC address, the HDD serial number...